# HandlerInterceptorAdapter postHandle method has ModelAndView as null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I extended `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`, and my class is handling the `postHandle()` method. But after debugging I find that the `ModelAndView` object passed to the `postHandle()` method is `null`. Please let me know what could be the most common reasons , so that I can investigate in that direction.

Comment: add some code to the question.

Comment: Actually the codebase is large, and I have no access to complete source. But can you please give some hints in general when this could happen.

Comment: sorry :) we're not magicians over here.. "no code" == "no help" :)

Comment: Ok will try to see if I can post some code. Thanks.

Comment: If a controller doesn't return anything, handles the request himself for instance, there is no `ModelAndView`. This is generally the case with download controllers for instance.